# Symfony 3, relación con entidad con doble PK

Tags: symfony3, symfony

tengo un problema con la consulta a una table con una doble PK. La consulta a la base de datos que realiza symfony solo la hace por uno de los dos campos y, por lo tanto, el resultado devuelto no es correcto.

En el problema intervienen 3 tablas: Medias, Contacts y Charges. Cada "contact" por cada "media" tiene un "charge".

Cuando realizo la consulta $contact = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Contacts')->getContact($id); me devuelve todos los "medias" del "contact" pero dentro del "media" el campo "charge" no es el correcto ya que el select que realiza symfony hace el where por "media" pero no por "contact".

Todo el código que tengo hecho:

contacts.php:

```
/**
 * Contacts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="contacts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ContactsRepository")
 */
class Contacts
{
....

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Medias", inversedBy="contact")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="contacts_has_medias",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contact_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="media_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $media;

....
```

contactsrepository.php:

```
class ContactsRepository extends EntityRepository
{

public function getContacts()
{
  return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT c FROM AppBundle:Contact c ORDER BY c.Name ASC'
    )
    ->getResult();
}

public function getContact($idContact)
{

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
      ->andWhere('c.id = :idContact')
      ->setParameter('idContact', $idContact);

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    return $query->execute();

}
}
```

medias.php

```
/**
 * Medias
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="medias")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Medias
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Charges", mappedBy="media", cascade={"ALL"}, indexBy="contact")
 */
private $charge;

....
```

charges.php:

```
/**
 * Charges
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="charges")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"contact_id", "media_id"})
 */
class Charges
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="charge", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $charge;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Contacts")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $contact;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Medias", inversedBy="charge")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $media;

public function __construct(Contact $contact, Media $media, $charge)
{
    $this->media = $media;
    $this->contact = $contact;
    $this->charge = $charge;
}
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Accediendo a `$media->charge` accedes a todos los registros `charge` vinculados con el `media`, no solo los que están vinculados al `media` y al `contact`, para acceder al registro correcto, usa los repositorios. En principio, los repositorios estandar de doctrine deberían bastar, algo así:

```
<?php
$contact = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Contacts')->getContact($id); // No es necesario, el método find($id) del repositorio por defecto hace lo mismo.
$media = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Contacts')->getContact($id);

$charge = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Charge')->findBy(['contact' => $contact, 'media' => $media]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Muriano, era exactamente lo que necesitaba!